# Highcharts Combination Chart: Column covering line series marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highstocks and I have both columns and lines inside a chart. The only problem is, the columns seem to cover up the line markers where I am using highstock instead of highchart. Here is my highstock fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6JACr/1/

And here is an example highchart fiddle where the column series doesnt cover the line marker.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

This bit of code probably isnt relevant but I need to add it or else stackoverflow wont let me post.

Here is my highstock series

```
accu_series = {
        name: "ACCU",
        data: accu_data,
        yAxis: 1
};
all_series[0] = accu_series;
nu_series = {
        name: "NU",
        type: "column",
        data: nu_data,
        stack: 0
};
all_series[1] = nu_series;
dau_series = {
        name: "DAU",
        type: "column",
        data: dau_data,
        stack: 0
};
all_series[2] = dau_series;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dassey/yx2k6/)

Just change the order of the charts. I think thats what decides whats on top.

```
function fill_series() {
    nu_series = {
        name: "NU",
        type: "column",
        data: nu_data,
        stack: 0
    };
    all_series[0] = nu_series;
    dau_series = {
        name: "DAU",
        type: "column",
        data: dau_data,
        stack: 0
    };
    all_series[1] = dau_series;        
    accu_series = {
        name: "ACCU",
        type: 'spline',
        data: accu_data,
        yAxis: 1,
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
            fillColor: 'white'
        }
    };
    all_series[2] = accu_series;
}
```